# How to unlock menu editing

Tags: menus

I'm trying to edit the menu,
arrow items are all locked
[image: editing menu]

I can't add new custom links or categorie.
How can I unlock the menu?

Comment: Sounds like JavaScript may be turned off. What browser are you using, do you have anything blocking JS?

Comment: Check the browser console for possible JS errors.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try with another browser.
2. Check your browser console : Ctrl + Maj + I Or right click and
   inspect.

   If you find error : First try to disable each plugin one after the
   other. In order to find out which plugin can generate the errors.

   OR

   -Modify the wp-config.php file and change (or add this) :

> define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', false ); 
> define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );

by

> define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);  
> define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);

-Go back to your menu page and click on the arrows. 
-After that open your debug.log file in the
wp-content folder and check for errors and try to fix them.